# How to set item value of a custom config class in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a custom config class named `my_custom_config_file.php` in codeigniter that is autoloaded. I want to set a config item value in that file using the codeigniter config class function `$this->config->set_item('item_name', 'item_value');`.

But what it does, it sets the config item for the default ci config class not my custom config class. When I access my custom config item by using `$this->config('item_name', 'my_custom_config_file')`, the item value is unchanged.

So the question is how one could set an item value in a custom config file?

Comment: is the item_name the same in both config files?

Comment: item_name only exists in the custom config file

Answer (score 0):

If you have autoloaded the `my_custom_config_file` custom config file, and since the `item_name` is only existed on `my_custom_config_file`, then you could set the custom config item just like setting up the primary config file item :

```
$this->config->set_item('item_name', 'item_value');
```

No need to mention the custom config name, since normally the config files will be merged into one master config array. And to retrieve an item from your `my_custom_config_file` config file, you could just use the primary config fetching method :

```
$this->config->item('item_name');
```